# TwitterAPI 1.1 REST API の 画像取得方法について

Tags: twitter

Twitter REST APIを使用して tweet を取得しています。  
tweet に複数の画像が添付されている場合、2枚目以降の画像が取得できません。  
公式リファレンスも確認しつつ、以下のサイト（古い情報ですが）も確認している状態です。

```
Twitter Rest APIのツイートオブジェクトの徹底解説 (エンティティの処理)
http://apitip.com/twitter-5.html
```

仕様として取得するのが無理なのか、公式に記載されていないようなクエリを投げれば取得できるのか、教えていただけますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[複数画像の tweet](https://twitter.com/TwitterSportsJP/status/569292363937349633?lang=ja) を REST API (https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json) を使用して取得したところ `extended_entities` に格納されているようでした。実際に取得したレスポンスを https://gist.github.com/KAMEDAkyosuke/3e3b25fa066d4f7fdb5f に用意しました。

Comment: 実際に取得結果までいただきありがとうございます。
こちら確認させていただきます！

Comment: ツイートを単体で取得するAPIでを使用しておりますでしょうか？ @Kyosuke Kameda

説明不足で申し訳ありません。
検索ワードを投げて、ツイート一覧を取得した際に複数画像ついているツイートの画像も取得したいと思っております。
以下のAPIを使用しております。
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets

http://apitip.com/twitter-5.html
↑にも extended_entities に入っているとのことでしたが、
json の結果を見てみても extended_entities の文言はありませんでした...

Comment: はい。ツイートを単体で検索する API < https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/show/%3Aid > を使用しております。検索の API では取得できません。

Comment: そうなんですね、わかりました、ありがとうございます！